# how to assign the images based on values from response using angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

i am working on a application, wherein it has a graph section. i need to show the images based on 1,0,-1.
i have to bind the images respectively based on the response.
In demo i am not able to display the images even though i gave google links.
Please help me to bind the values along with the images through response.

HTML:

```
<tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td scope="row">PSF. &nbsp;&nbsp;$8.25</td>
                      <td><img class="graph-arrows" src="../../../assets/images/up-arrow.png"></td>
                      <td><img class="graph-arrows" src="../../../assets/images/double-arrow.png"></td>
                      <td><img class="graph-arrows" src="../../../assets/images/down-arrow.png"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <br>
                  </tbody>
```

Ts:

```
this.propertiesPerMonth = [{
      "costPSF": { "market": 1, "region": 0, "national": -1 }
    },
    {
      "variances": {
        "expenses": [
          { "expense": "Janitorial", "market": 1, "region": 0, "national": -1 },
          { "expense": "Electricity", "market": 0, "region": 0, "national": -1 },
          { "expense": "HVAC", "market": -1, "region": -1, "national": 1 },
        ]
      }
    }
    ]
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bavwp9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a link to the image, not the page containing the image, thus that URL should end with an image extension like .PNG or .SVG, for example the first url should be this https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/32/32028.svg
To get this url, right-click the image and "Open Image in new Tab"

Comment: thanks for response, il do this, can u pls help me to bind the images as per the response

Comment: You should have an *ngFor that iterates over that JSON object, inside it have an *ngIf="expense.market == 1" and src="yourUpArrowSrc", repeat that 0 and -1, and do the same for expense.region and expense.national. Take a look at Font-Awesome or use Angular Material Icons, you can use images but these are much better.

Comment: in my application, i have used the images given from client, but here i was not able to put images so

Comment: ya i have used ngFor also but it doesnt work properly, from ts itself we need to handle i hope so for values with 1,0 and -1

Comment: upload the files to the assets folder, i will try to do it for you

Comment: images are fine, but i need to pass respective images based on response json data. that is the main target for now, could u pls help me in binding data

Comment: here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zlbtm8 , this question is solved please upvote and accept answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, i need these to happen dynamically, here we are giving data manually, the array properties per month comes from the api hit, so we will not know what the values are, so with the only one *ngFor we need to do

Comment: I hope for now, this is fine, if my senior doesnt agree then il get back to you

Comment: That's a third question, just change you object with the one you get from api, everything else stays the same, is your question answered? if so mark as solved please.

Comment: ya il vote, now i have one issue, i have images in assests folder, do i need to mport those to ts?

Comment: i had upvoted and accepted ur answer, pls help me to solve this

Comment: i have like this,  arrowUp ="../../../assets/images/up-arrow.png";
  arrowDown="../../../assets/images/double-arrow.png";
  arrowDouble="../../../assets/images/down-arrow.png";

Comment: yes you can do that, or just make them like they were in your post's HTML

Answer (score 1):

In your demo, your are links to google pages, not actual images. Try replacing them with actual images and they will work.

E.g. try the link "https://onaliternote.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/wp-1480230666843.jpg" as an example.

Comment: thanks for response ya i did that, i need to bind values from response pls help me out